# Use same database on main domain & sub domain in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a main domain https://www.pearltutorial.com and I also have a subdomain http://besttutorial.pearltutorial.com

I want both the domains to use the same database when visited. I've tried using Multisite but it isn't working.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Take a look at this plugin [Multiple Domain Mapping](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-domain-mapping-on-single-site/) I think it's what you are looking for

Comment: Should be able to use Multisite with the subdomain option enabled. If you need to get data from one "blog" to another you can use the [switch_to_blog()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_to_blog/) function.

Answer (score 0):

**Generally, that's not possible.**

Because, each WordPress installation has its own settings, post data, tags, etc. Every WordPress installation is unique and so its database. What you're asking for, is a custom application.

Also, never give the same database credentials to both the WordPress installations. It doesn't work that way and you end up with some alien stuff.

But **it's possible** if...

you are a coding pro, and you could build your own fork of WordPress that can extract data from a foreign database and insert into its own.

Or, you can build an API for your existing WordPress database and can call it from your custom-built application and process the data.

Even if you successfully implemented that, you end up losing your search rankings as it would become **duplicate** content [the same content on two domains or pages]. Google penalizes you.

Either way, you should be a pro. As far as I can understand, what you want is a special domain to showcase your best tutorials. You can implement that by creating a special post or tag category, `best` and tagging those posts under the `best`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you need more than one WordPress installations but you are limited MySQL Database allowance. In that case, multiple WordPress Installation into a single database is possible and it's not so difficult.

1. The first of all you must install WordPress manually.
2. During the installation in your wp-config.php phase, you need to change the prefix "wp_" in order to allow multiple installations. For example, the first can be "wpptl_" and the next can one be "wpbptl_".

You can use different prefix and use them to create as many installations as you need.